# Solved: Calculating the average around numpy array element error: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, numpy

EDIT: I have changed my code below presenting the working version, thanks to @hpaulj

I am trying to solve the 2D Laplace equation using Gauss-Seidel iteration: every non-boundary element in the matrix is replaced by the average of the surrounding matrix elements. I first create the basic matrix.

```
# creation of matrix using random values and boundary conditions.
matrix = np.random.random((4,4))
for n in range(4): matrix.itemset((4-1, n), 10)
for n in range(4): matrix.itemset((n, 4-1), 0)
for n in range(4): matrix.itemset((0, n), 0)
for n in range(4): matrix.itemset((n, 0), 0)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.33285936  0.59830215  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.07021714  0.45341002  0.        ]
 [ 0.         10.         10.          0.        ]]
```

Using the following code snippet, I try to find the left, right, up and down element around each non-boundary element in my array.

```
# opening the matrix and preparing it to be read and rewritten.
#with np.nditer(matrix, op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
with np.nditer(matrix, op_flags=['readwrite'], flags=['multi_index']) as it:

    # loop to find each element in our matrix
    #for index, x in np.ndenumerate(matrix):
    for x in it:
        #row, colum = index

        # only non-border values may be adjusted
        if x != 0 and x != 10:
            row, colum = it.multi_index

            # finding each element around x
            left = matrix[row][colum-1]
            right = matrix[row][colum+1]
            up = matrix[row-1][colum]
            down = matrix[row+1][colum]

            # finding average of elements around x
            newvalue = 1/4*(left+right+up+down)
            x[...] = newvalue
```

Instead of replacing the values, python prints out the following error:

```
x[...] = newvalue
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

I don't get the error if I just use

```
for x in it:
```

but then I cannot keep track of the x, y values in my array. Does anybody know how to keep track of the position of the element or resolve the error?

Comment: `x` in the iteration is the value at slot in `matrix`, but it is not a reference to that slot.  As the error says, it's a number.  `matrix[row, col] = newvalue` should work.

Comment: The iteration variable for `nditer` is a reference to the slot, a 0d array.  `x[...]=newvalue` does work for that.  Do a `print(type(x))` in both loops to see the difference.  There's no point in nesting the `ndenumerate(matrix)` loop inside the `nditer` context.

Comment: There is a `multi-index` option in `nditer` if you want to track `row/col`, https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.nditer.html#tracking-an-index-or-multi-index

Comment: I suspect this code would run faster if you used nested lists instead of an array.  You aren't make much (if any) use of `numpy` array methods.  List iteration is faster (and `nditer` does not help!).

Comment: @hpaulj I thought numpy arrays would be faster. This array is currently very small, but for the final program, it will be 100×100 large. Will nested loops still be faster?

Comment: `numpy` arrays are faster when using the compiled whole-array methods.  But iteration on them, in Python code, is slower than iteration on a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use of numpy index to set the matrix:

```
In [358]: arr = np.random.random((4,4))                                                                
In [359]: arr[[0,3],:] = 0                                                                             
In [360]: arr[:,[0,3]] = 0                                                                             
In [361]: arr[3,1:-1] = 10                                                                             
In [362]: arr                                                                                          
Out[362]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.8869947 ,  0.61765067,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.92640868,  0.83014953,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , 10.        , 10.        ,  0.        ]])
```

or even:

```
In [363]: arr = np.zeros((4,4))                                                                        
In [364]: arr[1:-1,1:-1] = np.random.random((4-2,4-2))                                                 
In [365]: arr                                                                                          
Out[365]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.50803298, 0.78055366, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.98941105, 0.61842531, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
```

I suspect your other iteration can be rewritten to make good use of array methods, but I won't tackle that now.

Here's the difference that I mentioned in the comments:

```
In [367]: with np.nditer(arr, op_flags=['readwrite']) as it: 
     ...:    for x in it: 
     ...:        print(type(x), x) 
     ...:                                                                                              
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.0
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.0
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.0
...
In [368]: for index,x in np.ndenumerate(arr): 
     ...:     print(type(x),x) 
     ...:                                                                                              
<class 'numpy.float64'> 0.0
<class 'numpy.float64'> 0.0
<class 'numpy.float64'> 0.0
....
```

and the use of multi_Index:

```
In [369]: with np.nditer(arr, op_flags=['readwrite'],flags=['multi_index']) as it: 
     ...:    for x in it: 
     ...:        print(type(x), x, it.multi_index) 
     ...:                                                                                              
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.0 (0, 0)
...
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.5080329836279988 (1, 1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0.7805536642151875 (1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I am not too concerned about speed. The code is working thanks to your suggestions. Thank you!